# no polyfills for document.register working in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, polyfills, web-component

Let assume I'm writing the following web component or custom element:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="js/MutationObserver.js"></script>
    <script src="js/CustomElements.js"></script>

    <script>
      var proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

      proto.createdCallback = function() { console.log('created');};
      proto.enteredViewCallback = function() {};

      document.register('x-foo', {prototype: proto});

      document.createElement('x-foo');
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

([polyfill on github](https://github.com/oliver-moran/custom-elements))
This works in Chrome. But when I try to run this in PhantomJS I get the following error:

```
TypeError: instanceof called on an object with an invalid prototype property.

http://localhost/~me/js/CustomElements.js:18
http://localhost/~me/js/CustomElements.js:217 in instantiate
http://localhost/~me/js/CustomElements.js:333
http://localhost/~me/js/CustomElements.js:342 in createElement
...
```

If you want to reproduce, here is my phantomjs script

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://localhost/~me/test.html', function() {
  phantom.exit();
});
```

I've tried other polyfills like

- https://github.com/Polymer/CustomElements
- https://github.com/mozilla/web-components

but actually none of them worked. Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't the shim for watch() and unwatch() at https://gist.github.com/384583 work in phantomjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998981/why-doesnt-the-shim-for-watch-and-unwatch-at-https-gist-github-com-384583)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It was solved with this polyfill :
https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element

You'll need to use the document.registerElement method.

Comment: Link only answers are not good idea. Please explain more and address the problem in your post. Then for more information add some links.